IIS 10 on Windows Server 2022
I'm migrating from Windows Server 2012 R2 to Windows Server 2022 due to Microsoft de-supporting 2012 R2.
I installed IIS and all the needed components and copied my application from the old server to the new server. When I open IIS Manager, I get this screen:

The screen on the Windows 2012 R2 server looks like this:

There's a lot of options missing and nothing I do adds them. I've tried numerous suggestions. One of the suggestions was to uninstall and re-install IIS. Well, it won't uninstall. I tried adding the missing options using Powershell, same result.  And of course the web site doesn't load. I'm stumped.
I can't uninstall ANY of the components, when the computer restarts there's a message that says "Updates could not be completed" and the components are still marked "installed" in the list. I found this link https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/May/25/Automating-IIS-Feature-Installation-with-Powershell which had a script to install via powershell, but same result. Components I need do not show in IIS Manager.
Anyone got any idea how I can fix this?
********* UPDATE ******
I got tech support from my hosting provider involved and they gave me a new server and install the basic IIS components.  But I needed ASP.NET and other app development features installed as well and they wern't installed.  So I gave it another shot at installing them.  FAILED.  This is an image of IIS Manager after the app development features install:

This is an image of the Add Roles and Features GUI showing that they were installed:

I requested tech support again.  Very frustrating.

What have you tried? Install ASP.net?

Windows CBS can be easily broken and stuck. Please restart from a clean Windows Server 2022 (such as from the installation media).

Unfortunately I can't install a clean copy of Windows, I rent a VPS from a hosting service and I have to rely on them to do the install.  I was hoping that there was something I could do independent of an install.  But its increasing looking like I'll have to have them do that.  Already have a support message in asking them to look at this.

install the missing windows features, what is the business related question or error in here?

The components I need to run my web based applications with IIS are missing, namely HTTP Features, ASP.NET, SECURITY and some of the SERVER COMPONENTS and they won't install no matter what method I use to do that.  I think it's obvious that the Windows installation is corrupt and needs to be re-installed unfortunately.

You give us no details; you reiterate that you've tried something that didn't work... What?

I thoughtI was pretty clear on that, but in the interest of clarity I'll add to the question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have the hosting company review the Roles and Features between the 2012R2 and 2022 servers.
In the 2022 there are likely roles missing. Below is an example from a Windows 2022 Server that is used for IIS.
There are multiple ways (GUI and Powershell, etc.) for the hosting company to get the list of current IIS Roles and Role Services for IIS from the 2012R2 server.
Instruct them to add the same IIS Roles / Role Services to 2022 server.
If this is a public facing server, I would strongly suggest getting someone involved that is comfortable advising you on security ramifications of the IIS settings.


Already have looked at this, the screen shows that all the components have been installed.  I can't uninstall ANY of the components, when the computer restarts theres a message that says "Updates could not be completed" and the components are still marked "installed" in the list.  I found this link https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/May/25/Automating-IIS-Feature-Installation-with-Powershell which had a script to install via powershell, but same result.

@PrescottChartier that "Updates could not be completed" message is what I referred to as broken CBS. Please keep pushing the VPS support, and I bet they are likely to give you another server instead.

I'll take whatever works.  Given that support takes the weekend off, it'll be until tomorrow before I have an answer.

Why the DV? Please explain what was in error or what was lacking in the context of the OP's question? If you're going to DV, then why not take the time to provide a better answer?

.... and they gave me another server, apparently they couldn't fix it either.
Sometimes I think people DV something just because they can.  I don't see anything wrong with your answer.

@PrescottChartier   10-4 on that. Good luck on the new server.

Nope, new server won't install the .Net or asp stuff .... same issue as the old server, it won't install, says it IS installed but also won't uninstall.  Windows 2022 is looking like a cluster f^^k ... I'm definitely not impressed.

@PrescottChartier  Do you happen to need .net framework 3.5? Its install files are not included with 2022 (or 2019, 2016, etc.) Windows Server ISO. It must be installed manually, via DISM, or other means. Just an FYI, there really isn't anything that much different between IIS versions on any of the servers.

Or .NET 4.8?, or asp?  Server manager says that installed too, but no sign of it.  And no ASP.NET components in ISS Manager, which would be in the Application development Section, which isn't there either.  If it were just .NET 3.5, there wouldn't be a problem.

@PrescottChartier To confirm, you aren't confusing .NET 4.8, ASP .NET 4.8, and .NET Extensibility 4.8? These are three different things. The .NET 4.8 is a feature that is installed via powershell or GUI and not part of IIS. The ASP .NET 4.8, and .NET Extensibility 4.8 are also installed via powershell or GUI, but are part of the IIS. You might need all three. No harm, no foul by installing all three if you aren't sure. You could then uninstall one at a time until the app fails.

I need them all, but they won't install.  The GUI says they're installed, but IIS manager says they're not (ASP.NET), the Application Development components are missing.  Note the 2012 server image in my question, I realize that 2022 arranges things differently, but they should be there if they're installed properly. I got another support request in.

I updated my question.

@PrescottChartier Looking at your updated question, your IIS looks to be appropriate. Has the server been rebooted to finish the install? At this point, don't assume that it is an IIS issue. Don't talk yourself into assuming a problem with 2022. There really isn't anything that special about it.

Then where are the App development components?  I see them in the 2012 server, but not the 2022 server.

@PrescottChartier ensure that .Net 4.8 is installed as a feature. This is separate from IIS. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net48   You need the developer pack installed for App Development. This is allows the ability to create apps instead of just installing them.
